# Usage of ATG PaymentGroupMapContainer

Tags: e-commerce, atg

I looked through documentation and some of the source code too, but am not able to understand the exact use of `PaymentGroupMapContainer` . I have a sample code - `getPaymentGroupMapContainer().addPaymentGroup(ITEM_DESC_GIFT_CARD, giftCard);` and in a similar way other payment groups are also added to the container. What if we have multiple gift card, how should this be handled? I am just not able to get the reason why PaymentGroupMapContainer exist

Answer (score 0):

As you've rightly identified, a `PaymentGroupMapContainer`, can only contain one payment type of type `ITEM_DESC_GIFT_CARD`. However an `order` can contain more than one `PaymentGroup` so to add multiple giftcards to the same order you need to adjust your logic slightly.

First ensure that you create a new `PaymentGroup`

```
GiftCard giftCard = (GiftCard) getPaymentGroupManager().createPaymentGroup("giftCard");
```

Now when you need to apply the giftCard:

```
getPaymentGroupManager().addPaymentGroupToOrder(order, giftCard);
```

Obviously there is a lot more to do around getting the GiftCard configured but the above should resolve your original problem about adding multiple GiftCards to a single order.

Comment: Thank you - Does this mean that PaymentGroupMapContainer just provides an overview of the TYPE of payment groups in an order?  In that case, I assume that we would need to execute getPaymentGroupMapContainer().removePaymentGroup(ITEM_DESC_GIFT_CARD); when ALL the gift cards are removed from the order?

Comment: An order can have more than one `PaymentGroup` so the container is a representation of the payment type in this particular `PaymentGroup` and not the order itself.